# How do I write a wrapper for a macro without repeating the rules?

Tags: macros, rust

I am trying to make a wrapper for a macro. The trouble is that I don't want to repeat the same rules in both macro. Is there a way to do that?

Here is what I tried:

```
macro_rules! inner {
    ($test:ident) => { stringify!($test) };
    ($test:ident.run()) => { format!("{}.run()", stringify!($test)) };
}

macro_rules! outer {
    ($expression:expr) => {
        println!("{}", inner!($expression));
    }
}

fn main() {
    println!("{}", inner!(test));
    println!("{}", inner!(test.run()));
    outer!(test);
    outer!(test.run());
}
```

but I get the following error:

```
src/main.rs:8:31: 8:42 error: expected ident, found test
src/main.rs:8         println!("{}", inner!($expression));
                                            ^~~~~~~~~~~
```

If I change the `outer` macro for this, the code compile:

```
macro_rules! outer {
    ($expression:expr) => {
        println!("{}", stringify!($expression));
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

`macro_rules!` is both *cleverer* and *dumber* than you might realise.

Initially, *all* input to a macro begins life as undifferentiated token soup.  An `Ident` here, `StrLit` there, *etc.*  However, when you match and capture a bit of the input, generally the input will be parsed in an Abstract Syntax Tree node; this is the case with `expr`.

The "clever" bit is that when you substitute this capture (for example, `$expression`), you don't just substitute the tokens that were originally matched: you substitute the *entire AST node as a single token*.  So there's now this weird not-really-a-token in the output that's an entire syntax element.

The "dumb" bit is that this process is basically irreversible and mostly *totally invisible*.  So let's take your example:

```
outer!(test);
```

We run this through one level of expansion, and it becomes this:

```
println!("{}", inner!(test));
```

Except, that's *not* what it looks like.  To make things clearer, I'm going to *invent some non-standard syntax*:

```
println!("{}", inner!( $(test):expr ));
```

Pretend that `$(test):expr` is a single token: it's an expression which can be represented by the token sequence `test`.  It is *not* simply the token sequence `test`.  This is important, because when the macro interpreter goes to expand that `inner!` macro, it checks the first rule:

```
    ($test:ident) => { stringify!($test) };
```

The problem is that `$(test):expr` is an expression, *not an identifier*.  Yes, it *contains* an identifier, but the macro interpreter doesn't look that deep.  It sees an expression and just *gives up*.

It fails to match the second rule for the same reason.

So what do you do? ... Well, that depends.  If `outer!` doesn't do *any* sort of processing on its input, you can use a `tt` matcher instead:

```
macro_rules! outer {
    ($($tts:tt)*) => {
        println!("{}", inner!($($tts)*));
    }
}
```

`tt` will match *any* token tree (see the [Macros chapter of the Rust Book](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/macros.html)).  `$($tts:tt)*` will match *any* sequence of tokens, without changing them.  This of this as a way to safely forward a bunch of tokens to another macro.

If you need to do processing on the input *and* forward it on to the `inner!` macro... you're probably going to have to repeat the rules.

Answer (score 0):

I had some success with the `$($stuff: expr),+` syntax.

```
macro_rules! println {
    ( $($stuff: expr),+) => {
    avr_device::interrupt::free(|cs| {
    uwriteln!(unsafe { &SERIAL_STATIC}.borrow(cs).borrow_mut().as_mut().unwrap(),
    $($stuff),+)
    })
    }
}
```